# Two legends in ggmap

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggmap

I ran this code:

```
columbus <- get_map('columbus', zoom = 11) 

ColumbusMap <- ggmap(columbus, extent = "device", legend = "topleft") 
Warning message:
`panel.margin` is deprecated. Please use `panel.spacing` property instead 

ColumbusMap + 
  stat_density2d(aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, 
                     fill = ..level.., 
                     alpha = ..level..), 
                 size = 2, bins = 4, data=all[all$year==2006,], geom = "polygon" ) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="red", high="royalblue")
```

I'm getting two legends, a grey one and a color one, and I only want one color.

Comment: You have one legend for alpha (the grey one) & one for fill (the colored one). Do you want to hide the alpha legend (easy), or incorporate it into the fill gradient legend (not as easy)?

Comment: This worked!  Thanks so much.  I wanted to get rid of the black and white legend and only keep the colored one.  This did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `guides(alpha=FALSE)` to the end of your code, like this:

```
ColumbusMap + 
  stat_density2d(aes(x = longitude, y = latitude, 
                     fill = ..level.., 
                     alpha = ..level..), 
                 size = 2, bins = 4, data=all[all$year==2006,], geom = "polygon" ) + 
  scale_fill_gradient(low="red", high="royalblue") +
  guides(alpha=FALSE)
```

Anytime you add fill, alpha, or color inside the aes(), you'll get a legend. Fortunately, these are very easy to remove by using guides() as shown.

Comment: @carljong - Are you still looking for an answer or was this solved? Please remember to click the check mark next to the solution to let the community know it's been solved and to help others find their answer even faster.